# Python equivalent of Ruby blocks for Sinatra-style URL routing

Tags: python, flask

Is there a way of recreating Sinatra's URL routing in Python? And are there any reasons why this might not be desirable?

From Sinatra:

```
get '/' do
    'Hello world!'
end
```

From Flask (using decorators for routing):

```
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"
```

Sinatra achieves this succinctness through Ruby blocks:

```
def get(path, opts={}, &block)
    conditions = @conditions.dup
    route('GET', path, opts, &block)

    @conditions = conditions
    route('HEAD', path, opts, &block)
end
```

I gather that Python does not have an exact equivalent of Ruby blocks, but that there are ways of recreating the functionality. How might this be done?

Answer (score 3):

As you said, Python doesn't have something like ruby blocks. Decorators are the commonly used solution for routing. The other way would be creating a list/dict containing the routes but since you seem to want the route definitions next to the underlying code, the decorator way is what you'll want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be using metaclasses, as it is done in webpy's [web.autoapplication](http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/apps/auto), [source code for that](https://github.com/webpy/webpy/blob/master/web/application.py#L471).

Answer (score 0):

So, to your second question of 'And are there any reasons why this might not be desirable?'.

- Having named functions makes it possible to do things `url_for(some_function)`, which makes it easy to restructure the site.
- named functions allow for testing, docstrings, etc.